# Functions not working: basic JQuery game

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a basic jQuery game where crystals on the screen have specific values, and the user is asked to click on the crystals and try to make the values add up to a random number.

There are 4 crystals with values, gemOne-gemFour. gemOne and gemTwo are working (i.e. the hidden values are adding up when the crystal is clicked) but gemThree and gemFour are not working (i.e. the hidden values are attached to the image when console logged, but nothing adds when the image is clicked).

The code for the latter two gems looks the same to me, so I'd love some ideas.

HTML Code for gems:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Crystal Game</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets\css\reset.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets\css\style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/game.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="white">
        <img src="assets\images\gem1.png" alt="gem1" class="gems" id="gemOne">
        <img src="assets\images\gem2.png" alt="gem2" class="gems" id="gemTwo">
        <img src="assets\images\gem3.png" alt="gem3" class="gems" id="gemThree">
        <img src="assets\images\gem4.png" alt="gem4" class="gems" id="gemFour"> 
        <div class="outline">
            <h6>Wins: </h6>
            <h6 id="winCount"></h6>
            <h6>Losses: </h6>
            <h6 id="lossCount"></h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class ="outline2">
        <h5>Random #:</h5>
        <br>
        <h5 id="randomSpace"></h5>
        <br>

        <br>
        <br>
        <h5>Your total score is:</h5>
        <br>
        <h5 id="scoreSpace"></h5>
    </div>

    <div id="bluebox">
        <h4>Crystal Collector</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="instructions">
        <h1>Instructions:</h1>
        <br/>
        <h2>1. You will be given a random #</h2>
        <br/>
        <h2>2. There are four crystals, each holding a specfic value</h2>
        <br/>
        <h2>3. Click on a crystal, and that value will be added to your score</h2>
        <br>
        <h2>Win = your total score matches the random #</h2>
        <br/>
        <h2>Lose = your total score goes above the random #</h2>
        <br/>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>Note: </h3>
        <br>
        <h3>-The crystal's value is hidden until you click on it.</h3>
        <br/>
        <h3>-Each time the game starts, the values will change.</h3>
    </div>

<!-- End of HTML -->

</body>
<div class="footer">
</div>
</html>
```

Javascript code in full:

```
// Step 1: make sure nothing runs until document is ready
$(document).ready(function() {

// Step 2: define variables for score, wins, losses, and random number
    var userTotal= 0;
    var wins = 0;
    var losses = 0;
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*101)+19;
    var cry1;
    var cry2;
    var cry3;
    var cry4;

// Step 2a: display wins and losses and total score
    $('#winCount').text(wins);
    $('#lossCount').text(losses);
    $('#scoreSpace').text(userTotal);

// Step 2b: display random number
    $('#randomSpace').text(randomNumber);

// Step 2c: function for game reset
  function reset(){
      randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*101)+19;
      $('#randomSpace').text(randomNumber);
      cry1= Math.floor(Math.random()*11+1);
      cry2= Math.floor(Math.random()*11+1);
      cry3= Math.floor(Math.random()*11+1);
      cry4= Math.floor(Math.random()*11+1);
      userTotal= 0;
      $('#scoreSpace').text(userTotal);
      } 
// Step 2d: function for displaying wins and losses
    function winning(){
    wins++; 
    $('#winCount').text(wins);
    reset();
    }

    function losing(){
    losses++;
    $('#lossCount').text(losses);
    reset()
     }

// Step 3: Assign numbers for each crystal, between 1-12
  var cry1= Math.floor(Math.random()*11)+1
  console.log(cry1);
  var cry2= Math.floor(Math.random()*11)+1
  console.log(cry2);
  var cry3= Math.floor(Math.random()*11)+1
  console.log(cry3);
  var cry4= Math.floor(Math.random()*11)+1
  console.log(cry4);

// Step 4: as user clicks the crystals, add up the total. If total = randomNumber, win and reset. if over, loss, and reset
    $('#gemOne').on('click', function() {
    userTotal += cry1;
    console.log("New total= " + userTotal);
    $('#scoreSpace').text(userTotal); 
    if (userTotal > randomNumber) {
            losses++;
            $('#lossCount').text(losses);
            alert("You lost, try again");
            console.log("you lost");
            reset();
        }
    if (userTotal == randomNumber) {
            wins++;
            $('#winCount').text(wins);
            console.log("you won");
            alert("You won! Congratulations!");
            reset();
        }
   });

   $('#gemTwo').on('click', function(){
    userTotal += cry2;
    console.log("New total= " + userTotal);
    $('#scoreSpace').text(userTotal); 
    if (userTotal > randomNumber) {
            losses++;
            $('#lossCount').text(losses);
            console.log("you lost");
            alert("You lost, try again");
            reset();
        }
    if (userTotal == randomNumber) {
            wins++;
            $('#winCount').text(wins);
            console.log("you won");
            alert("You won! Congratulations!");
            reset();
        }
   });

    $('#gemThree').on('click', function() {
    userTotal += cry3;
    console.log("New total= " + userTotal);
    $('#scoreSpace').text(userTotal); 
    if (userTotal > randomNumber) {
            losses++;
            $('#lossCount').text(losses);
            console.log("you lost");
            alert("You lost, try again");
            reset();
        }
    if (userTotal == randomNumber) {
            wins++;
            $('#winCount').text(wins);
            console.log("you won");
            alert("You won! Congratulations!");
            reset();
        }
   });

   $('#gemFour').on('click', function(){
    userTotal += cry4;
    console.log("New total= " + userTotal);
    $('#scoreSpace').text(userTotal); 
    if (userTotal > randomNumber) {
            losses++;
            $('#lossCount').text(losses);
            console.log("you lost");
            alert("You lost, try again");
            reset();
        }
    if (userTotal == randomNumber) {
            wins++;
            $('#winCount').text(wins);
            console.log("you won");
            alert("You won! Congratulations!");
            reset();
        }
   });

});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ff3mnp96/  Other than there not being a score space element in the markup you provided, I don't see an issue with this logic.

Comment: The scoreSpace id is in the html, and is being updated fine with the first two gems. I just didn't include it here.

Comment: So that aside, your stated issue of `the hidden values are attached to the image when console logged, but nothing adds when the image is clicked` is not replicated in that fiddle which is a straight copy of the logic you provided.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your last comment. What is not being replicated?

Comment: You're issue.  In that fiddle if I click the gem three or gem four, it does indeed add to the total.

Comment: And I added the full html file, it's been updated above.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ff3mnp96/1/  still works

Comment: Strange. Not sure why it's not working on mine.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. A css div was extended over the crystals and not allowing the crystal click to register. Thanks for your help!